# Android Ksoap2_3.1.1

Tags: java, android, wcf, android-ksoap2

I have Wcf 4.5 Service that is has two endpoints

- endpoint address="gzip" binding="customBinding"
  bindingConfiguration="gzipCustomBinding"
  contract="OTTServiceModel.IOTTService"/>
- endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding"    bindingConfiguration="customBasicHttpBinding"    contract="OTTServiceModel.IOTTService"/>

AS you can see first endpoint is using GZip compression format. When I call my Service on Android device using Ksoap2_3.1.1 with endpoint address that is not compressing result everything is fine, I get result.
When I call service that is using Gzip format there is an Error: Bad Request (400, tracked that using Wireshark). Content-Type *application/x-gzip* and *Accept-Encoding:gzip* are properly set.
This is part of code:

```
HttpTransportSE t = new HttpTransportSE("myServiceUrl");
ArrayList<HeaderProperty> headerProperty = new ArrayList<HeaderProperty>();
headerProperty.add(new HeaderProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-gzip"));

t.call(global.SOAP_ACTION + "MyMethod", envelope, headerProperty );
```

Here is a sample of request of gzip endpoint Wcf service:

P

```
OST /MyService/Service.svc HTTP/1.1

User-Agent: ksoap2-android/2.6.0+

SOAPAction: http://tempuri.org/IOTTService/MyMethod

Content-Type: application/x-gzip

Accept-Encoding: gzip

Host: myipAdress

Connection: Keep-Alive

Content-Length: 692



<v:Envelope xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:c="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
 xmlns:v="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><v:Header />
 <v:Body>
<MyMethod xmlns="http://tempuri.org/" id="o0" c:root="1">
<myParameter i:type="d:string">355113055997235</myParameter>
</MyMethod></v:Body></v:Envelope>
```

If I call this service using .net App everything is fine.
Any help, would be appreciated.